# How to change the type of a variable

Tags: c, casting

Let's say your terrible boss gives you the following task:

Write a function that returns the second byte of a `long`. Here are the requirements:

- Use the following function signature: `uint8_t second_byte(uint32_t l);`

A bit twiddling solution that comes to mind is:

```
uint8_t second_byte(uint32_t l)
{
  uint8_t b = (l >> 8) & 0xFF;
  return b;
}
```

Boss comes back with another requirement

- Don't use bit twiddling!

You purchase a Boss Voodoo Doll and proceed:

```
uint8_t second_byte(uint32_t l)
{
  uint8_t b = ((uint8_t*) &l)[1];
  return b;
}
```

Boss feels bossy, hands down another requirement:

- Don't de-/reference!!

Go and purchase some bomb-making manual and masking tape. After a few head scratches you come up with the following scheme:

```
typedef union {
   uint8_t  u8[4];
  uint16_t u16[2];
  uint32_t u32;
} long_u;

uint8_t second_byte(long_u l)
{
  uint8_t b = long_u.u8[1];
  return b;
}
```

Clean and beautiful.
You go to your boss and present the solution.

Boss mentions first requirement (function signature). You argue with your boss about this silly requirement, fruitlessly: You're boss's boss handed this requirement down.

Can anyone think of a way to 'change' the type of a variable. something like this (but code that compiles):

```
uint8_t second_byte(uint32_t l)
{
  uint8_t b = ((long_u) l).u8[1];
  return b;
}
```

By 'change' I mean write code that convinces the compiler to treat a variable of type `T` as type `T'` **without generating extra instructions** (like bit twiddling and de-/refrencing)

Compiler Optimization NOTE: some compilers (e.g. GCC) may optimize the above attempts to code that adds no instructions. some may not (e.g. IAR). I'm looking for a C language construct that is not dependent on compiler optimization.

Endianness NOTE: I don't want to focus on endianness issues. just imagine the `uint32_t` is a 4-byte struct

Simply put, I have a variable of type `T` associated with an area in memory. I want to have another variable of type `T'` associated with the same area without possible instruction-cost (de-/refrencing)

Comment: You realize that the "de-referencing" code should actually generate _zero_ extra instructions if you have a decent compiler, right? (Try taking a look at the generated assembly code to confirm that.)

Comment: All that code depends on machine endianess and **second byte in long** term is just bad and ambiguous..

Comment: Your boss is terrible, giving you such a task without taking endianess in consideration. I guess it doesn't matter though, since everything in this question is nonsense in real world programming anyhow.

Comment: This sounds like a bad interview question - why would a real boss care about this stuff in real development?

Comment: `#define T T'`. Anyone who gives such an assignment desires such a "solution."

Comment: It should be mentioned that your first example is not equivalent with the rest.

Comment: @DaoWen: the IAR compiler for Renesas seems to add instructions

Comment: @Lundin : If we take an example of IP Address stored as `long`, then the knowledge of endian-ness of machine is very important for reading correct address.

Comment: just imagine the `uint32_t` is a 4-byte string, not possible. Well you can say: just imagine the `uint32_t` is an array of 4 `char`s in little (or big) endian order.

Comment: The correct solution to the problem is to **change boss** and go work for a company with sane coding guidelines.

Comment: @0xF1: changed my wording: 4-byte struct. Please ignore endianness. It is not the focus of the question

Comment: What about my answer? I mean why do you feel that is not correct, please comment!!

Comment: This question assumes that adding extra operations (such as “bit twiddling” or dereferencing) or function calls results in additional instructions or function calls in the generated code. This is false. The compiler generates instructions to perform the computation specified by the C code, not instructions to emulate the C code in assembly/machine language. Due to the method of generation, there is often a large correlation between these when optimization is turned off, but it decreases when optimization is on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "change", just "copy":

```
uint8_t second_byte(uint32_t l)
{
  uint8_t temp[2] ;
  memcpy( temp, &l, sizeof(temp)) ;
  return temp[1] ;
}
```

My next step in horribleness would be to contemplate assembly.

Comment: It should be noted that this will give different result on systems with different byte order.

Comment: But on all systems it will get the "second" byte.

Comment: True, rephrased my comment.

Comment: your solution adds instructions and a function call

Comment: @woolstar - there is no such term **second byte in long** - you may have second byte in array of bytes but not in long. It is ambiguous.

Comment: @Artur: There is such a thing as the second byte of a `long`. It is defined by the implementation, per C 2011 (N1570) 6.2.6.1 2: “Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number, order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Just because long is composed of bytes it does not mean that there is such term as **second byte in long**. Your quote does not say anything about second byte of long. It only shows that objects are composed of bytes so still the term is not right and ambiguous. ;-)

Comment: @Artur: The second byte is the byte after the first byte, accessed via `* ((char *) x + 1)`. There does not need to be a specific definition of a term; the words not defined by the C standard have their usual technical or common English meanings.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Although I use it every day - english is not my first language which is easily concluded from my posts/comments. Nevertheless there are some very literate in english and programming people commenting this question for whom problem (although easy) is ambiguous. That is why there are quite a few comments about endianess here. I really respect your comments and encourage you to continue to comment my posts/comments. I am still eager to learn but we do not have to agree (I guess again ;-)

Comment: @woolstar: I'll upvote if you change formal parameter name from small 'L' to sth different ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use pointer to `union` to typecast:

```
uint8_t second_byte(uint32_t l)
{
     uint32_t *lp = &l;
     uint8_t b = ((long_u*)lp)->u8[1];
     return b;
}
```

this compiles on my system without warnings (with `-Wall` option also)

**NOTE**: Correctness of code may depend on endian-ness of the machine.

Comment: this causes extra instructions (on my IAR compiler)

Answer (score 0):

A simple cast works fine for me with gcc:

```
uint8_t second_byte(uint32_t l)
{
  return ((union { uint8_t u8[4]; uint32_t u32; })l).u8[1];
}
```

Declaring an intermediate variable would probably be more readable (and avoid possible compiler warnings about the cast):

```
uint8_t second_byte(uint32_t l)
{
  union { uint8_t u8[4]; uint32_t u32; } data;
  data.u32 = l;
  return data.u8[1];
}
```

These two version of the function produce *identical machine code* when I compile with gcc with at least `-O1` optimization enabled.

Actually, I'm seeing the *exact same machine code* for **every version of this function** in your question and in my answer. That includes the bit-shifting version. Most modern compilers are *very* smart. Worrying about bit-twiddling optimizations is usually kind of pointless because the compiler will do it better than you, and you're only sacrificing readability to get the exact same performance.

Comment: It should be noted that this will give different result on systems with different byte order.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - The spec was to "Write a function that returns the **second byte** of a long." If it were to return the second-least-significant byte, then the byte order might be an issue. Then again, the spec might just be wrong and it _should_ be byte-order-independent.

Comment: I use IAR and get `cast to type "union <unnamed>" is not allowed` error. sucks

Comment: @EmbeddedProgrammer - The second version should work for you even if the first version does not. But, that's beside the point. My main point here is that **this is all pointless since every version of the function yields the same machine code**.

Comment: "The second byte of a long" could mean anything. To be unambiguous, the question had to be phrased as "the second byte in the memory where the long is allocated", or indeed "the second most/least significant byte of a long".

Comment: IAR compiler for Renesas does not yield the same machine code. each version adds its own instructions

Comment: Since question is asked by **Embedded** Programmer and (s)he says **IAR** is his IDE it mean Atmel AVR but since AVRs are 8bit cpus endianess is compiler stuff here.

Comment: @Lundin: “The second byte of a long” cannot mean anything; it means the second byte in the representation of a long, which must be defined by the implementation per C 2011 (N1570) 6.2.6.1 2: “Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number, order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil With your C glasses on, certainly. From the view of the CPU/ABI, it could mean anything, especially since some MCUs allow both big and little endian.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this

```
typedef union {
        uint8_t  u8[4];
        uint16_t u16[2];
        uint32_t u32;
} long_u;

uint8_t second_byte(uint32_t l)
{
        long_u u;
        memcpy(&u,&l,sizeof(l));
        return u.u8[1];
}
```

Comment: adds instructions and a function call